# Oracle Developer Tools 12 install fails claiming I have Windows XP. I have Windows 7

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2010

I got **ODTwithODAC121021** [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index-097110.html) It installs the Oracle Client, ODAC, and ODT bits.

When I run the installer, the prerequisite check fails with this:

**Reference data is not available for release "12.1" on the operating system distribution "Windows XP5.1".**

I **actually** have Windows 7 Professional SP1

Huh?

My intent is to get the ODT bits into Visual Studio 2010 so I can use Server Explorer and Entity Framework. I don't really need a new Oracle Client, I've already got one installed to match our 11g server version, but it seems I can't pick and choose with this installer, which won't run.

Suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bug in this specific version of the Oracle Installer. Here is the workaround:

After making sure the installer is not running, please open up this file in the staging area where you unzipped ODAC:

....\stage\cvu\cv\admin\cvu_config

And in that file change the CV_ASSUME_DISTID value that is there to 6.1

Then save the changes and run the installer again.

This will force the installer to assume you have Windows 7.

Comment: If anyone is getting this error with the newer 12.1.0.2.4 ODAC release or later please leave a note here.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well!

Comment: I updated that file, but the installation still failed with same error message.