# Unable to install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2015, oracle12c, odac

I have already installed Visual Studio 2015 and also installed Oracle12c latest version database and I'm trying to install Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio but it is showing the following error:

[image: Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio Install Screen]

On clicking next button it is showing the following error:

[image: error message]

What can I do to install Oracle Developer Tools?

Comment: From [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html): "ODT is free and supports Visual Studio 2013, VS 2012, and VS 2010". VS 2013 support was added in Version [12.1.0.1.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/newfeatures-084113.html)

Comment: Again from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html): "Oracle plans to offer a new version of the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio integrated with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. This new version is planned to be available within one month of Visual Studio 2015's Release to Manufacturing (RTM) date." - I guess you just have to wait

Comment: I got same issue but I had already installed vs 2010 ?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096640/oracle-developer-tools-12-install-fails-claiming-i-have-windows-xp-i-have-windo

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Thomas Oracle does not support Visual Studio 2015.

> Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio The Oracle Developer Tools
>   for Visual Studio (ODT) is a tightly integrated "Add-in" for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio. ODT is free and supports Visual Studio 2013, VS 2012,
>   and VS 2010

yet but it [plans to](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html).

> Oracle Announces Plans for Visual Studio 2015 Support Oracle plans to
>   offer a new version of the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio
>   integrated with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. This new version is
>   planned to be available within one month of Visual Studio 2015's
>   Release to Manufacturing (RTM) date. As with earlier releases of
>   Visual Studio, Oracle has partnered closely with Microsoft as part of
>   the Visual Studio Industry Partner Program to make this release
>   possible. Keep an eye on this page or follow us on Twitter for the
>   upcoming release announcements.

Comment: I got same issue but I had already installed vs 2010 ?! ODAC121024

Comment: Still facing this issue. I have VS2017 Community Edition. Any help please?